# WebClient and HttpWebRequest return error 404 not found when request send to my website

Tags: asp.net, httprequest

url of my website is "mywebsite.com".
I used the WebClient Class to send the request to the Url.

If url is "test.com", the webclient work true.

If url is "mywebsite.com",I got an error "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

In other words, if url be my domain name webclient class return error not found.
this problem not exist in localhost (work true by url="mywebsite").

I try by HttpWebRequest but HttpWebRequest such as Webcline not work by url="mywebsite.com" and return error 404 not found and work true for other domain.

WebClient client = new WebClient();

```
        client.DownloadData("mywebsite.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if site bindings on IIS are correct or DNS entries are valid?